# Check if user input is equal to a array value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some code that compares the user input to a value in an array. If the user input match, i want to display an img equal to the input value.

Like this: User inputs the letter A, A is equal to letters[0], so display the img A.png.

Been trying for a while, but cant seem to get it to work? Do i need to use an associative array

```js
window.onload = btn;

function btn() {
  document.getElementById("btn").onclick = generateLetters;
}

// Array containing every letter in the alphabet
var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "Æ", "Ø", "Å"];

// Array containing a img equal to the letter
var letterImages = [letters[0] = "img/A.png", letters[1] = "img/B.png", letters[2] = "img/C.png", letters[3] = "img/D.png"];

function generateLetters() {

  // Get user input and convert to upper case to match array value
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value.toUpperCase();
  // Loops through letterImages array
  for (var x = 0; x < letterImages.length - 1; x++)

    // Loops through letters array
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
      // Check if input is equal to a value inside letters array
      if (letters.indexOf(input) > -1) {
        // Show img equal to input value
        document.getElementById("img").src = letters[x];
      }
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<button id="btn" type="button">Generate Letter</button>
<p id="print"></p>
<img id="img" height="50px" width="50px">
```

Comment: `letters` is an array of type string, so `letters[x]` will return a string. So when you set it to src, it will never get the file as you are not passing a src.

Comment: In your `// Array containing a img equal to the letter` you're reassigning values of `letters` array, note that your `letters[0]` will be `img/A.png`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: You also have two `"A"` in your `letters` array, that's why even though you're rewriting your first instance of "A" (as stated in my previous comment) it still finds the second one

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of Object in wich you save each letter and associated image:

```js
$( "#btn" ).click(function() {
    var letters = [ 
    { letter: "A", img: "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=One" },
    { letter: "B", img: "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/874787/0011ff&text=Two" },
    { letter: "C", img: "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/a697a6/6569ab&text=Three" }
];

// Get user input and convert to upper case to match array value
var input = document.getElementById("input").value.toUpperCase();

var found = letters.find(l => l.letter === input);

if (found) {
    document.getElementById("img").src = found.img;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text">
<button id="btn" type="button" click="displayimg();">Generate Letter</button>
<p id="print"></p>
<img id="img" height="50px" width="50px">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply build your array this way.

```
var letterImages = [{"a": "img/A.png"}, {"b":"img/B.png"}, 
{"c": "img/C.png"}, {"d":"img/D.png"}];

function generateLetters() {

  // Get user input and convert to upper case to match array value
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value.toUpperCase();
  var item = letterImages.find((item) => item[input])

  if (item) {
    // Show img equal to input value
    document.getElementById("img").src = item[input];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's a 1-1 correlation between input and filename, you can do away with all the loops and arrays. Simply check to see if the input is between A and Z, and if it is, add the image source using that input.

```
if (/[A-Z]/.test(input)) {
  document.getElementById("img").src = `img/${input}.png`;
}
```